# Userform lockups using loops not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set up my user form to do a loop or look up to reference my table which is on a sheet and is a large data base.

I want my user form to look up what I type and then auto fill in the other textboxes so that I can limit the number of duplicates and make it more stream lined.

My code is as shown below is embedded into `Textbox1` and is set up to run the code after change. It is still not working and I have worked for many days and weeks trying to figure this out.

```
Option Explicit

Dim id As String, i As String, j As Integer, flag As Boolean

Sub GetDataA()

If Not IsNumeric(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value) Then
    flag = False
    i = 0
    id = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

    Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""
        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
            flag = True
            For j = 2 To 7
                UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
            Next j
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    If flag = False Then
        For j = 5 To 10
            UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
        Next j
    End If
Else

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When the test `IsNumeric` fails, you shouldn't enter your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to adopt this refactoring of your code

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetDataA()
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim f As Range

    With UserForm1 '<--| reference your userform
        If Not IsNumeric(.TextBox1.Value) Then Exit Sub '<--| exit sub if its TextBox1 value is not a "numeric" one

        Set f = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Find(what:=.TextBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| try and find its TextBox1 value along column "A" cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
        If f Is Nothing Then '<--| if not found
            For j = 5 To 10
                .Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
            Next j
        Else '<--| if found
            For j = 2 To 7
                .Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = f.Offset(, j - 1).Value
            Next j
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

note: if this sub is actually inside UserForm1 code pane than you can change `With UserForm1` to `With Me`

Comment: @Vicelikeelm, did you get through it?

Comment: Ok I have been looking through and trying to make it work for me, but I do need it to look up a value like a string so you code dose work but not for what I am doing.

Comment: I don't get you: does my code answer what you asked for in you _original_ question?

Comment: Yes but unfortunately someone edited my original question and took out a part I did not notice it till I went back and looked at it. I thank you for your time and effort in trying to help me although not entirely what i was hoping for but I will try and modify your code to hopefully work within my userform I hope.

Comment: I see. Should you get stuck with the _new_ issue you can come back with a _new_ post. While as to this post since my answer solved the _original_ question as I found it, you may want to mark it as accepted. thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!